# Why does the program close when I close the pop-up window in tkinter?

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, camera, omr

In my program to correct exams by camera (omr) with OpenCV2 and Python 3, it detects the USB camera, but not the program going to the laptop camera (the interior):

```
import tkinter as tk
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from imutils.perspective import four_point_transform
from imutils import contours
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import os
import time
import sys

# the time for results name
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

# video frame
width, height = 400, 600

if cv2.VideoCapture(-1) is True:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)
else:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)
sucess, frame = cap.read()
def process_bub():
    ## cam her

    cv2.imwrite("images/test10.png", frame)

    # load the image, convert it to grayscale, blur it
    # slightly, then find edges
    cap = cv2.imread("images/test10.png")
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(cap, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
    edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, 75, 200)

    # find contours in the edge map, then initialize
    # the contour that corresponds to the document
    cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                            cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
    docCnt = None

    # ensure that at least one contour was found
    if len(cnts) > 0:
        # sort the contours according to their size in
        # descending order
        cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

        # loop over the sorted contours
        for c in cnts:
            # approximate the contour
            peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
            approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)

            # if our approximated contour has four points,
            # then we can assume we have found the paper
            if len(approx) == 4:
                docCnt = approx
                break

    # apply a four point perspective transform to both the
    # original image and grayscale image to obtain a top-down
    # birds eye view of the paper
    paper = four_point_transform(cap, docCnt.reshape(4, 2))
    warped = four_point_transform(gray, docCnt.reshape(4, 2))

    # apply Otsu's thresholding method to binarize the warped
    # piece of paper
    thresh = cv2.threshold(warped, 0, 255,
                           cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

    # find contours in the thresholded image, then initialize
    # the list of contours that correspond to questions
    cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                            cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
    questionCnts = []

    # loop over the contours
    for c in cnts:
        # compute the bounding box of the contour, then use the
        # bounding box to derive the aspect ratio
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        ar = w / float(h)

        # in order to label the contour as a question, region
        # should be sufficiently wide, sufficiently tall, and
        # have an aspect ratio approximately equal to 1
        if w >= 20 and h >= 20 and ar >= 0.9 and ar <= 1.1:
            questionCnts.append(c)

    # sort the question contours top-to-bottom, then initialize
    # the total number of correct answers
    questionCnts = contours.sort_contours(questionCnts,
                                          method="top-to-bottom")[0]
    correct = 0

    # each question has 5 possible answers, to loop over the
    # question in batches of 5
    for (q, i) in enumerate(np.arange(0, len(questionCnts), 4)):
        # sort the contours for the current question from
        # left to right, then initialize the index of the
        # bubbled answer
        cnts = contours.sort_contours(questionCnts[i:i + 4])[0]
        bubbled = None

        # loop over the sorted contours
        for (j, c) in enumerate(cnts):
            # construct a mask that reveals only the current
            # "bubble" for the question
            mask = np.zeros(thresh.shape, dtype="uint8")
            cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, 255, -1)

            # apply the mask to the thresholded image, then
            # count the number of non-zero pixels in the
            # bubble area
            mask = cv2.bitwise_and(thresh, thresh, mask=mask)
            total = cv2.countNonZero(mask)

            # if the current total has a larger number of total
            # non-zero pixels, then we are examining the currently
            # bubbled-in answer
            if bubbled is None or total > bubbled[0]:
                bubbled = (total, j)

        # initialize the contour color and the index of the
        # *correct* answer
        color = (0, 0, 255)
        k = ANSWER_KEY[q]

        # check to see if the bubbled answer is correct
        if k == bubbled[1]:
            color = (0, 255, 0)
            correct += 1

        # draw the outline of the correct answer on the test
        cv2.drawContours(paper, [cnts[k]], -1, color, 3)

    # grab the test taker
    score = (correct / 5.0) * 100
    degree = correct
    print("[INFO] score: {:.1f}/10".format(degree))
    cv2.putText(paper, "{:.1f}/10".format(degree), (10, 30),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.imshow("Ohod Resuls", paper)
    cv2.imwrite("results/theResult" + timestr + ".png", paper)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

# --- functions ---
ANSWER_KEY = {}


def on_button():
    for i, var in enumerate(o_vars):
        ANSWER_KEY[int(i)] = int(OPTIONS[var.get()])

    print()


# --- main ---


OPTIONS = {
    'A': '3',
    'B': '2',
    'C': '1',
    'D': '0',
}

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('OhodO')
root.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: root.quit())
lmain = tk.Label(root)
lmain.pack(side ="left")

def show_frame():
    _, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    lmain.imgtk = imgtk
    lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
    lmain.after(10, show_frame)

show_frame()


def restart_program():
    python = sys.executable
    os.execl(python, python, *sys.argv)


def dic_clear():
    ANSWER_KEY.clear()




# --- OptionMenu ---

tk.Label(root, text='Answer Keys', bg='#aaa').pack(fill='x')

o_vars = []

for i in range(10):
    var = tk.StringVar(value='- select -')
    o_vars.append(var)
    o = tk.OptionMenu(root, var, *OPTIONS)
    o.pack()

# --- others ---

b1 = tk.Button(root, text='Ok', command=on_button)
b1.pack(fill='x')
b2 = tk.Button(root, text='Clear', command=dic_clear)
b2.pack(fill='x')
b3 = tk.Button(root, text='Results', command=process_bub)
b3.pack(fill='x')
b4 = tk.Button(root, text='Close', command=root.destroy)
b4.pack(fill='x')

root.mainloop()
```

The problem is in this code:

```
b3 = tk.Button(root, text='Results', command=process_bub)
b3.pack(fill='x')
```

1. When I click on the "result" button the program work perfectly, that is, it gives me the result for student paper which was put in front of the camera, and saves an image with the result on it. However, when I closed the popup window with the result on it, the program also closes? Why is this?

2- when i clicked (x) in the corner of popup window, the program closed not the popup window ?!.

This program (code) is in (GPL) so you can use it for free.

Comment: Unfortunatly your code doesn't show **how** you **open** the *popup window* and **how** you **close** the *popup window*. [Edit] your Question and **replace** your code with the relevant part.

Comment: Please try to reduce the code down to a [mcve]. You've posted what looks to be a lot of code that is not necessary to reproduce the problem.